# Обработка ошибок в методе класса

Tags: c++, qt, исключения, try-catch

Предположим, есть класс для работы с базой данный. Есть методы этого класса, которые обрабатывает возможные ошибки через if, записывая текст произошедшей ошибки в переменную класса lastError, посылающий сигнал о том, что ошибка произошла и возвращающий то, что должен вернуть метод в случае ошибки.

```
bool insertIntoSomeTable()
{
// нормальный ход выполнения программы
if( ошибка подключения )
{
 lastError=ошибка подключения;
 emit errorHasOccured(lastError);
 return false;
}
// нормальный ход выполнения программы
if( сервер не может принять данные)
{
 lastError=сервер не может принять данные;
 emit errorHasOccured(lastError);
 return false;
}

// нормальный ход выполнения программы

if( ошибка выполения запроса )
{
 lastError=ошибка выполения запроса;
 emit errorHasOccured(lastError);
 return false;
}

//и так далее 
return true
}
```

В итоге эти if-ы очень загромождают код метода. Нормальной ли практикой будет, если я переопределю свой класс исключений для бд и перепишу метод так:

```
  bool insertIntoSomeTable()
  {
    try
    {
    // нормальный ход выполнения программы
    if( ошибка подключения )
    {
      throw DatabaseException("Ошибка подключения");
    }
    // нормальный ход выполнения программы
    if( сервер не может принять данные)
    {
      throw DatabaseException("сервер не может принять данные");
    }

    // нормальный ход выполнения программы

    if( ошибка выполения запроса )
    {
      throw DatabaseException("ошибка выполения запроса");
    }

    //и так далее  
    return true
    }
    catch(DatabaseException& e)
    {
    lastError= e.what();
    emit errorHasOccured(lastError);
    return false;
    } 
  }
```

Ещё,конечно, можно сделать этот метод void, в самом методе делать только throw, а ловить ошибки где-нибудь уровнем выше. Но мне бы не очень хотелось делать так.
В общем, нормально ли будет использовать приведенный выше вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нормальной ли практикой будет, если я переопределю свой класс исключений для бд и перепишу метод так

Будет нормальной.

**Пример "неправильных" if-ов**

```
bool Func1() {
  if (err) return false;
  return true;
}

bool Func2() {
  if (err) return false;
  return true;
}

bool Func3() {
  if (err) return false;
  return true;
}

// ...

int MainFunc() {
  if (!Func1()) return -1;
  if (!Func2()) return -2;
  if (!Func3()) return -3;
}
```

В данном примере выше - явная двойная проверка. Сперва на действие, потом на код возврата. Вот так не нужно. Именно для такого случая, вернее - и в том числе, и придумали обработку исключений.

**Было бы правильно так**

```
void Func1() {
  if (err) throw myexception(1);
}

void Func2() {
  if (err) throw myexception(2);
}

void Func3() {
  if (err) throw myexception(3);
}

// ...

int MainFunc() {
  try {
    Func1();
    Func2();
    Func3();
  } catch(myexception &e) {
    // some
  } catch(...) {
    // some
  }
}
```

Но, если в вашем коде "проверки-не-проверяются" - пишите так, чтобы исключить многословность. В общем, читаем [Бритву Оккама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0))

Comment: спасибо. еще небольшой вопрос. унаследовал свой класс исключений от std::exception (class DbException : std::exception). Но, почему то исключения от него ловятся только если явно ловить catch(DbException& e), а если ловить  от базового  catch(std::exception & e), то он его не перехватывает и все завершается std::terminate. Почему?

Comment: Создайте отдельный вопрос и приведите свой код, иначе остается только гадать